# capturing my screen and searching for a rgb color and clicking it in a def. its getting stuck in the def and clicking over and over

Tags: python, pyautogui

i have a while true statement that runs a def att(). once i call att() in while true it will repeat it and wont go back to the while true.

```
def att():
    s = pyautogui.screenshot()
    for x in range(68, 1690, 5):
        for y in range(140, 975, 5):
            r,g,b = s.getpixel((x,y))
            if (r,g,b) == (155,15,19):
                print('attacking')
                pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
                pyautogui.click(x, y)
                sleep(3)
```

keeps printing "attacking" and clicking the first spot the color was found. only prints "test" once.

```
while True:
    openinvo()
    lowhp = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('lowhp.JPG', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=0.85)
    if lowhp is None:
        heal()
    s1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
    for x1 in range(68, 1690, 5):
        for y1 in range(140, 975, 5):
            r1,g1,b1 = s1.getpixel((x1,y1))
            if (r1,g1,b1) == (0,255,0):
                pass
                print('in combat')
                sleep(.3)
            if (r1,g1,b1) != (0,255,0):
                print('test')
                att()
                sleep(.3)
                




    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        break
```

i tried locating a color and clicking on it only if another color is not on the screen. it runs threw once then gets stuck in a loop of clicking the first location it found over and over.

Comment: the `while True:` will keep on repeating unless there s a break. The `def att()` has a double nested `for loop`, so it may take some time to complete one cycle...

Comment: you have missed imports, so please add them (`pyautogui`, `time`).  Also `sleep` in not defined....  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i had all the imports sorry i only added the part of code it was getting stuck in the loop. it was the spacing that was messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up finding the problem.

```
if (r1,g1,b1) != (0,255,0):
            print('test')
            att()
            sleep(.3)
```

needed moved back to the same line as the first for

```
s1 = pyautogui.screenshot()    
for x1 in range(68, 1690, 5):
    for y1 in range(140, 975, 5):
        r1,g1,b1 = s1.getpixel((x1,y1))
        if (r1,g1,b1) == (0,255,0):
            pass
            print('in combat')
            sleep(.3)
if (r1,g1,b1) != (0,255,0):
     print('test')
     att()
     sleep(.3)
```

this was working but other parts were coded bad haha.
but i kept getting recursion error so rewrote the whole code "still learning" but ended up making the color scans a function that runs every loop and returns if it finds anything. the main loop has a statement  where the actions take place when the right info is returned. runs like a top now haha.